# How to do recursive lateral join in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, recursive-query

I have a treelike data structure `Object -> package -> package -> .... -> package`. I have a query over table containing the Objects and I need to check if the topmost parent has a value set or not.

using only with recursive CTE will just give me all the packages and I don't know which is the topmost parent for my current object. With lateral join i can make a query per row to check for value but I can't seem to find a way to make a query that would work like recursive lateral join.

The output of the query should be a table containing all the values of Object and a value from the topmost package.

Is there a way to do it purely in SQL or do I need to have some intermediate data processing on server side?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear to me what you are trying to achieve, but:

> I need to check if the topmost parent has a value set or not.

This can be done by "carrying" the root information through the recursion. In the root query of the CTE, you can select the attribute you want to make available to every level. In the recursive part you simply take the attribute from the parent.

Something along the lines:

```
with recursive all_packages as (
  select t.*, p.some_column as root_value
  from the_table t
  where <condition to select the roots>
  union all 
  select t.*, p.root_value
  from the_table t
    join all_packages p on p.some_id = t.some_parent_id
  where p.root_value .... (do something with the root value)
)
select *
from all_packages;
```

Comment: Hmm... so i could start with select *, column from package where parent is null
union
select *,  packages.column from package 
join packages on parent_id = pagages.id

and then inside my query i just join my object with package and use the carried over column value